# Can sub folder of a persistent volume claim have different permissions per claiming pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I'v got multiple pods that mounts the same persistent volume (let us call it `shared/`). I would like to set different permissions for `shared/<some sub folder>` in different pods.  Can I do something like this?

I know I can set the group id of the entire volume using kubernetes `fsgroup` but I would like to control permissions of sub folders from within the mounting pod.

Comment: never saw this implementation, but its interesting. will try to help

Comment: back to this topic few times - seems it is not possinble. Pleasepost your own answer in case you ll find solution

Comment: so far after few my tries I can not say its currently possible, unfortunately